# Getting json data back from php without reloading

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms

I need to send a value from a form to php, get data from a database based on the posted value, store all the data in json and then change an input value to the value of the json. All that without reloading the page because I can't lose the stuff that user has input already in the form.

Here is the select where I get the value from:

```
     <select name="groupName" id="groupName" class="form-control message" onchange="group_select()">
        <?php 
            $user_id = $_SESSION["id"];
            $sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT group_name FROM SMAILY_groups WHERE user_id = '".$user_id."'");
            while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
                echo "<option value='".$row['group_name']."'>" . $row['group_name'] . "</option>";
            }
        ?>
        </select>
```

The changing of the value is handled by this function:

```
function group_select(){
    $.ajax({
            url:'send.php',
            type:'post',
            data:$('#smsForm').serialize(),
            success:function(data){

            }
        });
}
```

And php that handles it is this:

```
$groupName = $_POST["groupName"];
$user_id = $_SESSION["id"];
$stack = array();

$sql = "SELECT phone FROM SMAILY_groups_numbers t1 INNER JOIN SMAILY_groups 
t2 ON t1.group_id = t2.group_id WHERE t2.user_id = '".$user_id."' AND 
t2.group_name = '".$group_name."'";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    array_push($stack, $row["phone"]);


}
$stack = json_encode($stack);

$result->free();
```

Now I need to get the phone numbers that I got from the database, and assign them as a value to one of my input fields. I need to do this without refreshing the page. I'm pretty sure it's somehow done in the ajax success function but I just don't know how.

Comment: in your `success` function simply add `$("#your_input_id").val(data);` where `your_input_id` is the `id` of the input value you want to assign?

Comment: @Denisx that assigns my whole html file contents as a value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, it is done in the `success` callback. Actually it's pretty simple: Create a `<input type="hidden" name="phonenumbers" id="phonenumbers">` element in your HTML.

```
<select name="groupName" id="groupName" class="form-control message" onchange="group_select()">
  <?php
  ...
  ?>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="phonenumbers" id="phonenumbers" value="">
```

Then, on each request, append the returned value(s) to the value of that `<input>` element. Don't forget to add a separator though! I use comma.

For example:

```
function ajaxSuccessHandler (data) {
  var hiddenInput = document.querySelector('#phonenumbers');
  if (hiddenInput.value.length >= 1) {
    // if there are already one (or more) numbers in the hidden input
    hiddenInput.value += ',' + data.join(',');
  } else {
    hiddenInput.value = data.join(',');
  }
}
```

You can either call that function inside the `success` callback *or as* your `success` callback. So this:

```
function group_select(){
  $.ajax({
    url:'send.php',
    type:'post',
    data:$('#smsForm').serialize(),
    success: ajaxSuccessHandler
  });
}
```

or this:

```
function group_select(){
  $.ajax({
    url:'send.php',
    type:'post',
    data:$('#smsForm').serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
      ajaxSuccessHandler(data);
    }
  });
}
```

should produce the same result.

Comment: And – as you already said – have to `echo` the result, too :)

Comment: I still don't really get it, pretty much what I need is to have my input field be something like that after php has done it's thing. 
    <input type="hidden" name="receiver" id="receiver" value="123,456,789">
where the value is whatever values I got from my database. What this is for is that users can create groups and then send a mass text, maybe that helps understand what I need exactly.

Comment: Oh, OK... You cannot use the code I've written for it, because it tries to select one of the `<option>` elements inside your `<select>`. I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

You Can try this

```
 <select name="groupName" id="groupName" class="form-control message" onchange="group_select()">
    <?php 
        $user_id = $_SESSION["id"];
        $sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT group_name FROM SMAILY_groups WHERE user_id = '".$user_id."'");
        while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
            echo "<option value='".$row['group_name']."'>" . $row['group_name'] . "</option>";
        }
    ?>
    </select>
```

Javascript Code Dont Forget to Include jquery in your page head

```
    <script>
    function group_select(){
    let groupName = document.getElementById('groupName').value;
        $.ajax({
                url:'send.php?groupName='+groupName,
                type:'GET',
                success:function(data){
                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
//Field to which you want to sent value
                document.getElementById('fieldName').value = obj.variableName;
                }
            });
    }
    </script>
```

send.php will look some what like this

```
$groupName = $_GET["groupName"];
$user_id = $_SESSION["id"];
$stack = array();

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT phone FROM SMAILY_groups_numbers t1 INNER JOIN SMAILY_groups 
    t2 ON t1.group_id = t2.group_id WHERE t2.user_id = '".$user_id."' AND 
    t2.group_name = '".$group_name."'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo json_encode($row);
```